# jquery selectize error: issue with adding new select fields and combox-ifying them

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

I am trying to the Selectize library so I can have a comboboxes on my form.

So my form has a way to dynamically add more dropdowns (that i want to be comboboxes), so whenever the user adds a new dropdown, I want to apply Selectize combobox to it.  So within my function that adds the new dropdown, after I have appended it, I use the following code:

```
$('select').each(function() {
  if (!$(this).is('selectized')) {
    $(this).selectize({
      create: true,
      sortField: 'text'
    });
  }
});
```

I thought that this would only apply it to dropdowns that do not already have Selectized combo box applied to it, but something is going wrong. Basically it is applying it to new comboboxes but something strange is going on with the existing ones. It's adding some kind of blank dropdown each time.

I tried to look around but I cannot find an "official" solution for combobox-ifying a newly added select fields.  I don't know if it's an issue with how I am applying it, or if it's some kind of weird conflict with twitter bootstrap or jquery-ui or jquery itself (I included all of those in the fiddle)

Anyways, here is a link where you can see this issue in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/Qz7Ar/2/

Does anybody have experience with this or know what's going on here?

**edit:**

I also made a fork removing jquery-ui and bootstrap, so it's just jquery (required for Selectize) and Serialze, and the issue is still happening:

http://jsfiddle.net/Wxxub/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay well I figured out how to fix it..

If I add an `id` attrib to the new element and target by that instead, it works.  Here is another fork demonstrating it:

http://jsfiddle.net/Wg7J6/1/

I can't find anywhere in the Selectize doc that it's necessary (I could be blind though!) that the select field must have an id or if it would work without one but i'm just doing it wrong or what, though.